# Highcharts loop JSON Object to fill data series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am very new to Java Script and I am trying to figure out how to loop through my JSON object and fill the Highcharts data series with the following JSON object. I have mocked up a static display of what I am trying to do with JS Fiddle. [JsFiddleLink](https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/2yvu7z41/18/)

Can someone please help me on this?

## here is my JSON object that I want to loop through and fill the Highcharts data Series.

```
{
    "OuterKey": {
        "v4_acl": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 40,
            "S2": 30,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 10
        },
        "v6_acl": {
            "aggregate": 120,
            "S1": 14,
            "S2": 13,
            "S3": 12,
            "S4": 11
        },
        "v4_qos": {
            "aggregate": 125,
            "S1": 30,
            "S2": 14,
            "S3": 17,
            "S4": 19
        },
        "v6_qos": {
            "aggregate": 80,
            "S1": 22,
            "S2": 21,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 23
        },
        "v4_nf": {
            "aggregate": 90,
            "S1": 20,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 26
        },
        "v6_nf": {
            "aggregate": 111,
            "S1": 11,
            "S2": 44.5,
            "S3": 45,
            "S4": 80.5
        },
        "baseline": {
            "aggregate": 130,
            "S1": 60,
            "S2": 10,
            "S3": 10,
            "S4": 10
        }
    }
}
```

## Also here is a screen shot of that static displayed rendered chart.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I have mainly been searching online for some sort of example of this being done. unfortunately I have not come across anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the transform you need:

```js
const raw = {
    "OuterKey": {
        "v4_acl": {
            "aggregate": 100,
            "S1": 40,
            "S2": 30,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 10
        },
        "v6_acl": {
            "aggregate": 120,
            "S1": 14,
            "S2": 13,
            "S3": 12,
            "S4": 11
        },
        "v4_qos": {
            "aggregate": 125,
            "S1": 30,
            "S2": 14,
            "S3": 17,
            "S4": 19
        },
        "v6_qos": {
            "aggregate": 80,
            "S1": 22,
            "S2": 21,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 23
        },
        "v4_nf": {
            "aggregate": 90,
            "S1": 20,
            "S2": 20,
            "S3": 20,
            "S4": 26
        },
        "v6_nf": {
            "aggregate": 111,
            "S1": 11,
            "S2": 44.5,
            "S3": 45,
            "S4": 80.5
        },
        "baseline": {
            "aggregate": 130,
            "S1": 60,
            "S2": 10,
            "S3": 10,
            "S4": 10
        }
    }
};

const seriesObj = Object.values(raw.OuterKey)
  .reduce((memo, v) => { 
    for (s in v) { 
      memo[s] = memo[s] || []; 
      memo[s].push(v[s]); 
    } 
    return memo; 
  }, {});
  
const series = Object.entries(seriesObj)
  .map(([name, data]) => ({name, data}));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'My JSON Chart'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'JSON VALUE'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: Object.keys(raw.OuterKey),
        crosshair: true
    },
    series
});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!, Thank you!, Thank you!

Comment: Hi, One quick question I noticed the data is not matching the correct key value's in the charts. I created another JSFiddle with another representation of this chart. in there I have the keys v4_in_acl -> OSPF_IPv4_Stream4 -> 3689187.5 if you see in the chart is displaying in the incorrect position of v6_in_net_flow rather than under v4_in_acl. I have been trying all day to try and fix that. Is there any way i can change that so data is represented correctly?

Comment: Here is the JsFiddle link. I think my actual data and the data I showed here are a little different and behavior is getting changed some. https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/4yuegoLd/13/